# Java global variables not updating in new class

Tags: java, global

I am currently programming a simple Android app that asks the user a series of questions and then tells them how many they got correct. I have one class that has a global variable (called "score") that is private and I have getter and setter methods for it. When the user gets the answer correct, the score is incremented (locally) and updates from 0 to 1 in that class. However, when I try to use the getScore() method I have created, to access the value of score in another class, it says scores value is 0, and not 1.
    E.g.

```
    public ClassA {
        private int score =  0;

        public void setScore(int s) {
           this.score = s;
        }
        public int getScore() {
           return score;
        }
    }

    public ClassB {
        private ClassA eg = new ClassA();
        private int score = eg.getScore();
    }
```

I've been stuck on this for a while and really don't know why this isn't working.
Help is much appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: make ur variable static

Comment: Where are you setting your score in class B?

Comment: Where is your code where you are incrementing those score variable ? And make it static first.

Comment: There is no global variables in java.You mean class variable ?

Comment: If the example code you've shown is purely just an example and your `ClassA` actually extends an Android class, I really hope it isn't the `Activity` class.

Comment: You haven't posted your actual code, and there are at least three errors in what you have posted.

Comment: @sureshatta : Well technically a `class variable` is declared as `static` in this case (in the OP's example) as it's non-static, it's an `instance variable`.

Comment: Thanks, people. Changing to static worked. @Squonk , it does extend the Activity class. Do you have any suggestions on how to make a quiz, with multiple questions (e.g. 30) without having to create 30 individual classes and activities?

Comment: @user1831081 : First point *NEVER* create public methods in an `Activity` (e.g., getters and setters) that you intend to be used by another `Activity`. Seriously...this is a bad idea and can cause major problems and often won't work. You can use `SharedPreferences` to share data between Activities or simply use a single `Activity` and change the view that holds the question, you can use an `Activity` with `Fragments` and `Fragment` callbacks. To repeat...the ANdroid `Activity` class is a "special case" class and shouldn't be treated like a normal Java class and should be self-contained.

Comment: @user1831081 : Also...if you post a question related to Android, please post the code (or at least shows skeleton code) showing the classes you're extending and don't put the Java tag on the question. Many Java programmers don't understand things like the `Activity` class and they'll wrongly advise you to make things `static` which can potentially break your app big-time. Let Android programmers answer Android questions...I'd worked out you were extending `Activity` even though you hadn't mentioned it in the question or showed it in the example code.

Comment: @Squonk , thanks very much. I never knew that having getters and setters in Activities were bad. I just thought that because it was Java, it would be okay. So, it would be possible to create a quiz, with multiple questions, by using a single activity but by changing the textview and buttons? Could you give me a code example showing the use of SharedPreferences or fragments? If you've got the time to do so. Next time, I'll remember to specify for Android specific problems. Thanks for your advice.

Comment: @Squonk , right now I have a really inefficient way of doing the quiz. I have 10 different Java classes, each one corresponds to an Activity,but I was hoping to have like 50 questions or more. Having 50 classes and activities clearly would not be a good idea. I'll try using the SharedPreferences and Fragments like you suggested.

Answer (score 2):

> **Set** the Score, **before** getting the Score.

```
public ClassB {
        private ClassA eg = new ClassA();

        eg.setScore(5);
        private int score = eg.getScore();
        System.out.println(score);
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I initially tried something like that, but I kept getting an error saying that "setScore() doesn't have a return type, so this can't be done". Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Can you show the code, the way you set the Score? I think something's up the way you might have used it.

Comment: public static Sharper sharp = new Sharper();
 
 public static int score = sharp.getScore();
 sharp.setScore(score);
It was something like that. I know you said to declare the setScore() first, but I wasn't sure of how to get the value from the other class and then add it in, before creating the score variable in this other class.

Comment: If you don't mind can you edit your question, and place the entire code there. It would help to debug it faster.

Comment: I've not got the version where I was setting the score first, but that was the way I was doing before I changed it. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Ok. No probelem, but remember you should set the score FIRST and then get the score.

Comment: Thanks. I will try and remember that in future.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure to actually increment the score in `ClassB`. Also make `score` a `static` variable.

Comment: Changing score to static seems to have worked. Thanks for everyones advice. They have all helped :)

Answer (score 0):

Edit your code like this :

```
   public ClassA {
    private static int score =  0;

    public void setScore(int s) {
       this.score = s;
    }
    public int getScore() {
       return score;
    }
}

public ClassB {
    private ClassA eg = new ClassA();
    int score = 0;
    if(answerCorrect())
    {
         score++;
         eg.setScore(score);
    }
    private int realScore = eg.getScore();
    System.out.print("Final Score : "+realScore);
}
```

And, create a method `answerCorrect()` to check whether answer is correct or not, this method will return `boolean`.

Comment: I will bear the answerCorrect() method in mind. I can imagine I will be needing something like that. Thanks :)