# RemoveAllViews not removing views

Tags: android, layout, android-view

I try to remove all child views of a linear layout but nothing is removed, the weird thing is the same code is working in another application. Here's the sample code of the method that populate the choiceHolder whenever a tab in it is selected (I remove all view and mark the selected one and populate basing on that:

```
/** a method to fill the upper bar where we choose the {@link CategoriesMyBox}
 * @param category
 */
private void fillNavigationBar( CategoriesGetter category) {
    TextView categoryTxt = new TextView(getActivity());
//      categoryTxt.setAllCaps(true);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams txtParams;
        if (category.isSelected() /*|| (category.getId_categorie()==0 && allselected)*/) {
        txtParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        txtParams.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
        categoryTxt.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        categoryTxt.setTextSize(categoryTxt.getTextSize());
        txtParams.setMargins(10, 0, 10, 0);
        categoryTxt.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
        if (category.getId_categorie() == 0) {
            categoryTxt.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.all_boxs));
        }else {
            categoryTxt.setText(category.getName_categorie());
        }
        categoryTxt.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
        categoryTxt.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.back_categories_selected));
//          categoryTxt.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#E3E8E6"));
        categoryTxt.setTag(category);


    }else {

        txtParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        txtParams.setMargins(10, 0, 10, 0);
        categoryTxt.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        categoryTxt.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
        txtParams.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
        if (category.getId_categorie() == 0) {
            categoryTxt.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.all_boxs));
        }else {
            categoryTxt.setText((category.getName_categorie()));
        }
        categoryTxt.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
        categoryTxt.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.back_categories));
//          categoryTxt.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#777777"));
        categoryTxt.setTag(category);
    }
    choiceHolder.addView(categoryTxt, txtParams);
    categoryTxt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            CategoriesGetter cat = (CategoriesGetter)v.getTag();
            id_cat = cat.getId_categorie();
            for (int i = 0; i < categories.size(); i++) {
                categories.get(i).setSelected(false);
            }
                cat.setSelected(true);
    //              choiceHolder.removeAllViews();
            /*for(int i=0; i<((ViewGroup)choiceHolder).getChildCount(); ++i) {
                View nextChild = ((ViewGroup)choiceHolder).getChildAt(i);
                choiceHolder.removeView(nextChild);
            }*/
            while (((ViewGroup)choiceHolder).getChildCount() >0) {
                View nextChild = ((ViewGroup)choiceHolder).getChildAt(0);
                choiceHolder.removeView(nextChild);
            }
//              choiceHolder.removeAllViewsInLayout();
            for (int i = 0; i < categories.size(); i++) {

                fillNavigationBar(categories.get(i));
            }
            callbackCategory.selectCategory(cat.getId_categorie());





        }
    });
}
```

choiceHolder is a `LinearLayout`.

and here's a picture showing the problems : [image]

Well all my application is behaving the same way even when updating the list inside i can still see the list that was before.

Comment: You need to post much more code, at the moment one can only guess what you are doing wrong: Are you maybe forgetting to clear the unwanted elements out of the `categories` list?

Comment: it's not only a problem in the list but in every component like the price range is a library that's working great in many of my apps but here you see the visual left out behind it's like a stack of pictures even if i replace a fragment in a frame i can still see the previous fragment in the back.

Comment: SHOW XML AND MORE CODES

Comment: `RunOnUIThread()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the solution i found for this problem is remove the `fullScreen` theme tag from the activity in the `AndroidManifest` it was like this :

```
<application
    android:name="com.paperpad.mybox.ApplicationInit"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.paperpad.mybox.activities.SplashActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.crashlytics.ApiKey"
        android:value="023e7fe8a4a93f93ffe7510201929d081b125313" />

    <activity
        android:name="com.paperpad.mybox.activities.BoxsMainActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_boxs_main"
        android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.paperpad.mybox.LoginActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_login"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateVisible" >
    </activity>
</application>
```

by removing `android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme"` from the activity `BoxsMainActivity`all worked. hope this helps someone...

Answer (score 2):

The best way to make sure something runs via a view is to run it via a post:
e.g

```
someView.post(new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        someView.removeAllViews();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using .invalidate() or .postInvalidate() on the choiceHolder?

Comment: This doesn't fix the problem, it's not only a problem with the choiceHolder but with the whole views of the application.

Comment: the fact that it is "final" means that you probably initialized that code block before it contained the views. Thus, when you use it, it probably didn't add them properly. We need to see more code. I have had this happen a number of times in my code...

Comment: @Jim the choiceHolder is a global variable (not a final one) initialized in the onCreateView method.

Comment: I get it. But the onClickListener is constructed when the object is constructed. "onCreate" is called subsequent construction. The variable is not static or synchronized, so you will have problems. For example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18239476/java-global-variables-not-updating-in-new-class

Answer (score 1):

In your xml file you can define for the same positions in your page more layouts , Let s say you have  a surface of the buttom of the page , you can define Layout 1 and Layout 2 with the same properties and one will have visibility gone , in your code you will change this at some actions and you will switch the visibility .

Answer (score 1):

The problem could be that choiceHolder must be declared as "final" to be called in "onClick" - placing the View calls in a runnable so that it is not declared as final should fix it. There's not a compiler error because it's valid to call a method and the method call could still result in the view appearing on the screen even though the parent layout ("choiceHolder") did not retain a reference to it that allows you to remove it.

Comment: The 'choiceHolder' is declared as a global variable. The thing that the same work on 35 application I already did the same principle...